# dcc32.cfg in delphi7 is modifiable?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Is there any importance of order of paths exists in dcc32.cfg? can we modify the order or can add some more paths to it as per our convenience?

Actually I have list of programs which are interdependent and I compile all of them using command line compiler.

So in this process does it checks order of path as well? Also found some of the paths missing from dcc32.cfg and I think adding them back can solve my problem.

Comment: You can specify the paths as command-line arguments to dcc32, for example in a build script (*.cmd). This overrides dcc32.cfg and has the side effect to serve as a documentation of your expected configuration and directory structure

Comment: @mnj - Thanks for prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the directories in a search path does matter if the file being searched for is found in more than one of the directories. For example, consider this search path:

```
dir1;dir2
```

If the file being searched for is in both dir1 and dir2, then the version found in dir1 will be used, because it is found first.

On the other hand, if the search path was:

```
dir2;dir1
```

then the version in dir2 would be used.

So, you can modify the order, but it changes the meaning of the search. Whether this has material affect for you, only you can know.

And yes you can add more directories to the paths, which also changes the meaning. Again, only you can know whether or not changes you make are appropriate.